# Gnuplot bars and line in a single plot, where bars are equidistant

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot bars and line in a single plot from the following data:

```
amount  cost    profit
64  22.915949   48.15697753
128 15.424979   56.41929322
256 9.473054    49.80545598
512 6.685107    96.8453052
1024    4.897494    56.82355225
```

So far I have come to the following plot:

[image: bars line chart]

Using this code:

```
set boxwidth 40.0 abs
set style fill solid 

set y2tics
set ytics nomirror

set grid y

set bmargin at screen 0.2
set tmargin at screen 0.9

# Set the graph title and axis labels
set title "Title"
set xlabel "Amount"
set ylabel "Cost"
set y2label "Profit"

plot 'data.txt' using 1:2:xtic(1) with boxes axes x1y1, \
     'data.txt' using 1:3 w lp pt 7 lw 2 ps 1 axes x1y2
pause -1
```

How can I make the bars not be separated but close together with a little constant separation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** use the pseudocolumn 0 for the x-values (check `help pseudocolumns`)

For example like this:

**Script:**

```
### bars and pseudocolumn
reset session

$Data <<EOD
amount  cost    profit
  64    22.915949   48.15697753
 128    15.424979   56.41929322
 256    9.473054    49.80545598
 512    6.685107    96.8453052
1024    4.897494    56.82355225
EOD

# Set the graph title and axis labels
set title "Title"
set xlabel "Amount"
set ylabel "Cost"
set ytics nomirror
set y2label "Profit"
set y2tics

set boxwidth 0.8
set style fill solid 0.4

plot $Data u 0:2:xtic(1) w boxes axes x1y1 ti "Cost",\
        '' u 0:3 w lp pt 7 lw 2 axes x1y2  ti "Profit"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]